# On the continuity of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, continuity

> Examine the continuity of these functions on $[0,1]$
>
> $a)$ $f(x)=\frac{\sin{\frac{1}{x^2}}}{x^2}$ if $x \neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$
>
> $b)$ $g(x)=x (-1)^{[\frac{1}{x}]}$ if $x \neq 0$ and $g(0)=0$
>
> $[x]$ is the integer part of $x$

For the first function:

It is continuous for $x \neq 0$

For $x=0$ we consider the sequences $x_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n \pi+ \frac{\pi}{2}}} \to 0$ and $f(x_n) \to + \infty $

So $f$ is not continuous at $0$

Now the second function is more tricky and i would like someone to help me verify my reasoning.

For $x=0$ we have that $|f(x)| \leq |x| \to 0=f(0)$ thus $f$ is continuous at zero.

Now assume that we take for instance $x= \frac{1}{2}$

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{1}{2}^-}f(x)= \frac{1}{2}$$
because if $x \to \frac{1}{2}^-$ then $[\frac{1}{x}] \to 2^+$ thus conider $A=\{x\in [0,1]| 2<\frac{1}{x}<3\}$ and if $x \in A$ then $[\frac{1}{x}]=2 \to 2$

so $\lim_{x \to \frac{1}{2}^-}f(x)= \frac{1}{2}$

Also using the previous  argument we can see that $\lim_{x \to \frac{1}{2}^+}f(x)=- \frac{1}{2}$

So the limit of $f$ at this point does not exist thus $f$ is not continuous.

Is my reasoning correct?

Also can we say that the last function is discontinuous on the set $B=\{\frac{1}{n}|n \in \mathbb{N}\}$?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can even generalize it let it be tending towards $\frac {1}{n} $ so from RHS we will have$ [n+h]=n $ and from LHS we will have $[n-h]=n-1$ now for any integer(positive or negative not only natural numbers except $0$) we will have $(-1)^n\neq (-1)^{n-1} $ hence the function is discontinuous at every $\frac {1}{n} $ where $n $ is an integer except $0$

Comment: is my reasoning correct in both functions?

Comment: I think your first answer cant be proved only with sequences instead you can use $-1\leq sin \leq 1$ so its just oscillating and has no limit.

Comment: but $\sin({2n \pi+ \pi/2})$ is 1 forall n?

Comment: the second function is ok assuming your answer.

Comment: Sequences in the first case are the simplest approach (and perfectly correct).

Comment: @Did how can we use two different sequences as we have to deal with $\infty $

Comment: ?? Sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ with $x_n\to0$, $y_n\to0$, $f(x_n)\to0$ and $f(y_n)\to\infty$.

Comment: @Did in my first function i found a sequence $x_n$ which goes to zero but $f(x_n)$ does not go to $f(0)=0$ .So from the sequentialy continuity of a function we deduce that the first function is not continuous at $0$..So this is correct ,isn't it?

Comment: @MariosGretsas Indeed if there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ such that $x_n\to0$ holds but not $f(x_n)\to f(0)$, then $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

Comment: Ok then..thank you for your help.